# JHipster: Change UI and renaming/deleting entities

Tags: jhipster

I'm fairly new to JHipster, have the following immediate questions:

1. How to switch to another UI, like for example PrimeNG? Where in the code and what do I have to change to switch from the default UI (which one is it by the way?) to PrimeNG?
2. How to remove created entities (with all of the created artifacts bound to it and code parts)? For example I just wanted to change the name of an already created entity, but couldn't find how, so I believed the most easiest way would be to delete the old one completely and recreate it again (with new name, etc.).

Cheers

Comment: 1. have a look at this jhipster module https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-jhipster-primeng 2. how did you create your entities: JDL or questions?

Comment: I created the entities with JDL.

Comment: 2. use git to delete some entities, it's a good practice to do a commit after each entity added, this way it's easy to delete and avoid forgetting some files

Comment: 2. you can manually delete all files from an entity and drop the table using liquibase. If you want to change entity fields and relationships you can run "yo jhipster:entity [entity_name]" and follow the instructions